# Unwanted code being inserted into pages

Tags: html, coldfusion, code-injection

Some of our ColdFusion sites are having the words "coupon" inserted into their footer with a link to another site. Is there anything I can do to prevent this? Is there any software I can run to help detect any vulnerabilities? It doesn't seem to be SQL injection as the databases seem fine and nothing unusual is showing up in the logs.

Comment: Have your ColdFusion templates actually been modified? Check them to see if you can find the "coupon" reference. This could be an issue on the end user's machine. They may have some malware installed that is injecting that code into your pages on their machine, not really on your server.

Comment: yeah the templates themselves are being modified on our server. it always seems to be in the footer next to the company logo.

Comment: "are being modified" or "have been modified"?

Comment: the files are being modified, the client then tells us they can see the coupon code on the website. we remove the code it happens again. we've checked the sites files and there isn't anything unusual in the code so we cant work out how it is being done.

Comment: As an initial step I'd be changing the passwords you use to access the server.

Comment: Check your site at http://hackmycf.com/. That should be the first step you do.

Answer (score 2):

There are several variations of attacks that produce this sort of result (appending a link to some malicious or nefarious site).  For example, this one ([Script Injection](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2009/9/18/script.insertion.attack.vector)) uses the latency between a file upload and checking to insert executable code on your server.

Other attack vectors include FTP (which is why you should not use it), or other file transfer protocols. In your case the infected machine may not be the server. It could be a *client* machine with access to the server - a developer who has set up FTP to the server for example.

Let me know if you need formal help - we have a good track record fixing this sort of thing. If you get more clues post them and I'll try to help. I will warn you that if this is a server infectionit is at the root level and is so pervasive your only option is to start with a pristine install and reinstall your code. Bad news I know - sorry :(

Comment: thanks for the advice mark. is there any software/malware checker you would recommend to run on the developer machines to help narrow down the problem? If it is a developer machine are there any logs I should be looking at on the server to narrow the problem down?

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is probably no. These attack vectors have a small footprint - they are not worth chasing for most scan companies since they only apply to servers. The weblogs, FTP logs (shut down FTP if you can) and all the CF logs (especially the cfusion-out.log) _might_ yeild some info. But anyone with this level of control over your server can certainly alter logs :)

Comment: Years ago, a major hosting company was targeted like this. After they patched their servers, we had to re-upload a number of sites on fresh servers. If this is your own server and you're not sure how it's vulnerable, I'd recommend hiring someone to help.

Comment: @csber3 - this is self interested but since Adrian brought it up, we have 3 folks here specializing in this. We'll be glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

We had something similar happen when one of our servers was hit by the hack Charlie Arehart describes here:

http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2013/1/2/serious_security_threat

Have you had these patches?

Comment: Upvoted.  When answer was posted, person did not have a high enough rep to post comments.

Comment: yeah we're running CF10 with all the latest patches applied.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that I would recommend is searching your site(s) for any use of the <cffile> tag that isn't expected.  I had a customer that somehow got a single file that was a backdoor to their site.  It was particularly dangerous because it could upload files to any location on the server as well as execute any SQL command against *any* datasource on the server.  In other words, this single file opened the door to all of the sites and databases that were running on that server.

This backdoor file (which was named vision.cfm) was often used to update footers with links to coupon and spam sites.  vision.cfm was only 210 lines of code.

The entire server had to be sanitized after this was discovered.